# Flexbox task with a few squares and @media change below 600px

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have this flexbox task to do and I am completely lost.

The end result should look like this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKvPk.jpg
The second picture is when the screen is at or below 600px ( the two blue squares to fall beneath the red one)
The text has to be the same 
Standart size of the container is 600px*500px and should be centered.
Here's a codepen link:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RQrmvE

```
* { 
  box-sizing: border-box 
} 
.flexbox {
  margin:auto;

}
.flexbox {
  width: 600px;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
 align-items: flex-start;
   flex-wrap: wrap; 
font-size:3em;

}

.flex-item {
  width: 100px;   
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

}

#flex-item-1 {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100px;
margin-top:20px;;
width:260px;
}

#flex-item-2 {
  background-color: green;
   height: 100px;
margin-top:20px;
width:260px;
}

#flex-item-3 {
  background-color: red;
  height: 350px;
width:350px;
margin-left:14px;
word-wrap:break-word;
}

#flex-item-4 {
  background-color: skyblue;
  height: 80px;
width:150px


}

#flex-item-5 {
  background-color: skyblue;
  height: 80px;
align-self:flex-start;
margin-bottom:20px;

}
```

Comment: We can't debug an image. Provide a _working code snippet within the question_, reproducing the issue described, not just a CSS fragment.

Comment: I added a codepen link, hope that is enough. Sorry for the way of me posting, this is the first time I post on this site, since I started studying front end development a few weeks ago.

Comment: Can someone respond please ?

Comment: Someone will, you just need to be patient and wait until someone get some spare time.

Comment: You won't be able to do this dynamically with Flexbox using the existing markup, so is a markup change allowed?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you are looking for - [Pen](https://codepen.io/gibinealias/pen/jZqOxw)

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.flexbox {
  width: 600px;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 25px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  font-size: 3em;
}

#flex-item-1 {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100px;
  width: 48%;
}

#flex-item-2 {
  background-color: green;
  height: 100px;
  width: 48%;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
}

#flex-item-3 {
  background-color: red;
  height: 320px;
  width: 350px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#flex-item-4 {
  background-color: skyblue;
  height: 150px;
  width: 175px;
  margin: 25px 0 0 auto;
}

#flex-item-5 {
  background-color: skyblue;
  margin: -150px 0 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  height: 150px;
  width: 175px;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  #flex-item-1,
  #flex-item-2 {
    height: 80px;
  }

  #flex-item-3 {
    height: 160px;
  }

  #flex-item-4,
  #flex-item-5 {
    height: 70px;
  }

  #flex-item-5 {
    margin-top: 25px;
  }

  #flex-item-3,
  #flex-item-4,
  #flex-item-5 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, really helped a lot. Now  I will spare some time to look at this and hopefully remember it next time i do flexbox, could you please explain whats the reason behind the flex items leaving the flex box using my "code" after I zoom in ( ctrl+) ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sure, I will work on that and get back to you soon. Meanwhile, if you find my solution right, you may up-vote it and and mark it as the correct answer. Thanks.

Comment: @ГеоргиДраганов - I believe its a bug with codepen as I don't see the issue in debug mode([link](https://s.codepen.io/gibinealias/debug/jZqOxw/bYMdyGQwvOZr)).
Please have a look.

Comment: Also CSS Grid is a much better and advanced way to achieve these sort of layouts. You may learn about that as well.

Comment: @ГеоргиДраганов Unfortunately doing it this way, you don't make use of Flexbox at all. This setup is no more flexible than using absolute positioning. As soon as you start adding content, it will break and/or overflow the boxes, and won't dynamically grow/shrink the items like a proper Flexbox version would.

Comment: @ГеоргиДраганов And the reason your "original code" items leave the flex box (container), is because of all the fixed values you use.